# Size of Pointer Variables

Tags: c, pointers, variables, size

Considering pch, pshort, pdouble declared as pointers to char ,short int ,double respectively, what would be the arrangement if the three variables were arranged according to their size ?

Comment: And which language is this?

Comment: @Bathsheba The language in question is C

Comment: OK, I've added the most important thing: the language tag.

Comment: When pointers have different sizes, a common situation is pointers to functions differ from pointers to objects.  Others differences are possible too.

Answer (score 3):

The facetious answer is you don't know. `char`, `short`, and `double` could all be the same size, and `char*`, `short*`, and `double*` could all be different sizes!

---

`sizeof(char)` is 1 by the standard. You can't have anything *smaller* than that, so it makes sense to put `char` first.

But `short int` could be the same size as a `long int`: the standard only specifies minimum ranges. And either could be larger than a `double`.

*Normally* a `double` weighs in at 64 bit, and a `short` 16 or 32 bits.

The **parsimonious** answer is `char`, `short`, `double`.

---

As for pointers, the standard allows `sizeof(char*)`, `sizeof(short*)`, and `sizeof(double*)` to all differ.

Comment: "All pointers are usually the same size." - Keyword is "usually" (not necessarily or always).

Comment: @Cppplus1: Nope, I started with talking about non-pointer types.

Answer (score 3):

Pointers to different types *may* have different sizes, although on most modern platforms they are all the same size (32 bits on x86, 64 bits on x86_64).

The requirements<sup>1</sup> are:

- Pointers to `char` and pointers to `void` have the same size and representation;
- Pointers to `struct` types all have the same size and representation;
- Pointers to `union` types all have the same size and representation;
- Pointers to qualified and unqualified versions of compatible types have the same size and representation (i.e., `sizeof (int*) == sizeof (const int *)`)
- Pointers to all other types may have different sizes.

---

1. C 2011 Online Draft, section 6.2.5, para 28.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer variables are usualy 64 bits on machines that can do 64 bit arthmetic, because that allows the machine to handle more than 2^32(4 billion, or 4 gigabytes) of RAM. In machines that can't handle 64 bit arithmetic, long pointers, which are slower and actually two poimters put together, that treat each maximum amount of RAM as an index in an array, must be used. Consequentially, long pointers are slower than regular pointer.

EDIT
Bethsheba reminded me, in a comment below that the pointer will usually not be 64 bits when in a register, but will usually be padded to 64 bits in memory for performance reasons (so, treat it as 64 bits).

Comment: On the current crop of Intel chips, pointers are actually 48 bits: C compilers pad them out to 64 as an act of kindness.